# Supply voltage drops AFTER connecting to device

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, adapter

I have a 19V 2.1 amp (power mentioned is 45 watt) laptop adapter connected to a 19V 2 amp laptop (in description power mentioned 10.2 watt).

When I plug the adapter, the multimeter shows the rated voltage, 19V. But when I connect it to the laptop, it does not charge. Then when I remove it and check the voltage, it does not even show 1 V; somewhere around 200mV.

What and where is the cause?

Comment: Is the plug polarity correct?  (What happens to the voltage of the computer?)

Comment: the inlet for the laptop is very small. so i took a diff adapter and sliced and joined with a small pin. the adapter had red and white wires and pin had red and black wires. joined black and white, red and red.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the cause? and where is the cause.

Impossible to know based on the information given. It could be any number of reasons. Most likely, you're triggering a resettable fuse in the power adapter due to an over-current situation when you plug it into your laptop. Possible causes could be:

1. The power adapter's plug has reverse polarity relative to the laptop.
2. The power adapter is faulty and is shorting internally.
3. The laptop's power receptacle is faulty (maybe a piece of metal is jammed in there or a pin is bent).

Also, your power numbers are a little funny. A power supply rated at 19V and 2.1A has a maximum capacity of 39.9W, not 45W.

Comment: And a power supply rated 19V 2A gives 38.0W not 10.2W.  If it is really only a 10.2W power supply then it's only putting out one fourth the requirements of the laptop which expects a 45W (or 39.9W) power supply.  Possibly the laptop is tripping a fuse in the second adapter simply by trying to draw more current than it can provide.

Comment: I like the reset-able poly fuse idea.

Comment: `The power adapter's plug has reverse polarity relative to the laptop.` - the inlet for the laptop is very small. so i took a diff adapter and sliced and joined with a small pin. the adapter had red and white wires and pin had red and black wires. joined black and white, red and red. i guess the outer portion is negative and the inner portion positive for the pin.

Comment: i tried to use the adapter this morning, and somehow it started working again. but i guess it will happen again

Comment: I found a funny behavior with my adapter. If the laptop is off and I connect it, it starts charging. But if I turn on the laptop first and then connect the charger, it wont charge. I have to first turn it off, connect and then turn on laptop.